# Discrepancy between types for adding and retrieving header values for IHeaderDictionary in Microsoft.Owin

Tags: c#, dictionary, types, owin, request-headers

In an OWIN app I'm making, I'm working with its `Request.Headers` property, which is a [`IHeaderDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.iheaderdictionary(v=vs.113).aspx) (a wrapper for owin.RequestHeaders and owin.ResponseHeaders which implements `IReadableStringCollection, Dictionary<string, string[]>, Collection<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>, IEnumerable`).

For me it makes most sense to think of it as a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`. When I add something to this dictionary, I need a `string` key and `string[]` value, which makes sense. So I'd do something like:

```
string key = "MyKey";
string[] value = new string[] {someString};
this.Response.Headers.Add(key, value);
```

However, when I try to retrieve values from this dictionary, I find that it returns `string`, not `string[]`. So if I do:

```
string[] value = this.Response.Headers[key];
```

I'll get a compiler error saying "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'. Instead, it works when I do:

```
string value = this.Response.Headers[key];
```

I'm afraid I'm missing something very obvious, but I figured I'd ask anyway.

**Update 1**

I found [this GitHub announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/60) to replace `string[]` with `StringValues`, which seems relevant, but I don't know how exactly it solves the issue.

Comment: if you can set StringValues struct type value in `this.Response.Headers.Add(key, value);`, then you can get array of string by calling [ToArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringvalues.toarray?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Primitives_StringValues_ToArray) method on StringValues struct.